# Only one sound playback at a time

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

For some reason reason I am only able to playback one sound at a time. This means I can't do a Skype conversation and, for instance listen to music streamed from Google Play or watch a Youtube video.
I can listen to VLC and YouTube or Skype/Teamspeak simultaneously.

When I open GNOME's sound applet and take a look at the applications-tab I can see "ASLA plug-in [plugin-container]" and VLC media player as seperate entries. Manipulating the ALSA plugin results in the sound-output of my browser, Skype or Teamspeak to change.

Why is it that it is either Skype (or Teamspeak) or my browser that can playback sound, but not all of them at the same time?

```
lspci | grep -i audio
```

Output:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, since I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: By playing on your browser you mean using Flash? If so, I think that the problem is on proprietary software-side, and there is little hope to solve it without the help of the developers.

Comment: Yes, I mean playback by Flash. Thanks for your input! Though I really think this is an alsa/pulseaudio problem. On my second computer I don't have problems while using Flash, Skype and VLC (for instance) simultaneously.

Comment: On your second computer do you have an ATI card too?

Comment: No, the second computer has an Intel Motherboard with an OnBoard Intel VGA Chip. (Sorry, I won't be able to provide the exact HW-spec, located in a different town). This opens a rather strange option, might the sound be working bad due to the Catalyst Driver (since it provides sound support for HDMI?!)?

Comment: I think so, but it is better to wait for someone more expert than me on proprietary hardware.

Comment: Still having this problem? Have you tried a newer version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I really can't recall how, or even if I fixed this issue. Anyway, with 14.04 everything works fine now.